# jQuery count checkboxes in divs with display: block but not display: none

Tags: jquery

I want to use jquery to count the number of checkboxes in a div but only when the div display is set to block, and not when it's set to none.  This changes based on button presses.

I've tried this so far:

```
$("div:#divid:visible").find('input:checkbox').length
$('input:checkbox:visible').length
$("div:#divid").find('input:checkbox.visible').length
```

What always seems to happen is, if include 'visible' then it always counts 0 checkboxes no matter whether their parent div is display:none or block, and if I don't include 'visible' it always counts all of the checkboxes, again ignoring the display status of the parent div.  The checkboxes themselves to not have a display property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra `:` in your first one, you want:

```
$("div#divid:visible").find('input:checkbox').length
//    ^---- No : here
```

Although the `div` at the beginning of that is pointless (harmless, but pointless) unless the element with `id="divid"` might be a `div` sometimes and not other times and you want to skip it if it isn't a `div`. More likely, just:

```
$("#divid:visible").find('input:checkbox').length
```

Although actually, you can do it with just one selector rather than calling `find`:

```
$("#divid:visible input:checkbox").length
```

Also note that you need to be sure that the relevant `div` is in the DOM and has the `display` setting you want to check when the code above runs, as it will look at things *as of that instant in time*.

Example - [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/oyosod/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/oyosod/1/edit)

HTML:

```
<div id="div1">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>
<div id="div2" style="display: none">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function($) {

  display('$("#div1:visible input:checkbox").length = ' + $("#div1:visible input:checkbox").length);
  display('$("#div2:visible input:checkbox").length = ' + $("#div2:visible input:checkbox").length);

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html("<code>" + msg + "</code>").appendTo(document.body);
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Result:

```
$("#div1:visible input:checkbox").length = 5

$("#div2:visible input:checkbox").length = 0
```

Comment: I tried this but it also didn't work.  Again, same behavior, either all are selected when I don't use visible, or none are selected when I do.

Comment: @CHP: Don't know what to tell you. If the div is hidden *when you execute the query above*, its child checkboxes will not be counted. If it's not hidden, they will be. See the live example I added.

Comment: You told me the correct thing in the comment :)  The script I'm trying to edit is complicated and not my own, but by moving the ('#divid:visible' 'input:checkbox').length to a different part of the script, it works.  I believe it must have been doing the selector multiple times before and after the div display had changed and producing the results I was seeing.  But now that I moved it to the very top of the function I was calling so that it's happening separate from any other code, it works.  I want to accept your answer but it's actually the comment that's correct.

Comment: @CHP: It's not uncommon for an answer to be fully useful only when you read the comments, but I've folded that info in.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  $("#divid:visible").find('input[type=checkbox]').length;
```

Comment: `'#divId :visible'` will match *all* visible elements *inside* `#divId` - There should be no space between `#divId` and `:visible`.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work.  I got the same behavior.  Nothing selected when I specify 'visible' and everything selected when I don't.